# Creating listView in android using data got by sql server

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, android-listview

I have got the data from my local sql to activity ... now I want to create a new activity called listView activity and I want to display a listView using the data I previously got. What is the best method to transfer data between activities and create an adapter for the listview?

Comment: Have you tried something so far ?. Do you have any progress ? Show us that you're trying to do something and we'll help you finished it.

Comment: I have tried intent.putextra to transfer data between activities. For the listView I am still reading if u have a good resource do share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using `Intent` to send data to the next activity is good but please don't send all the data from your database using Intent. The best way to implement this will be to create some data provider class which won't hold the actual data but can fetch it when it's needed

```
public class DataProvider {
    public Cursor fetchData() {
        // fetch the data here and return a cursor
    }
}
```

Than in your activity pass this object with the intent

```
Intent i; // init it
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("dataProvider", new DataProvider());
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

And finally in your started activity get the data provider - i won't write any code cause i believe you can handle this by yourself. When you got the `DataProvider` just call `fetchData()` method to fetch the data. It is very **IMPORTANT** to access db asynchronous or your activity may cause ANR, so the best way to do this will be using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). I will also let the implementation of AsyncTask to you.

If you have some troubles feel free to ask and we'll help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want to get a post and all its comment from the server and display it accordingly on the Android application. Will it be better if i use cursor method for the post and SQLite for comments.

Answer (score 0):

Create new intent and put data you want. You can put various types of data.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
i.putExtra(name, value); <--- with this you send data to next activity
startActivity(i);
```

And what about adapter, if you are not experienced with listviews use ArrayAdapter. Dont forget to use getView() method wisely :)

More: How you get resources in next activity? Well...
In onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) you do this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main2);
this.getParent().getIntent().get<DATA-TYPE-YOU-HAVE-SENT>("KEY-NAME");   //this can be anything you sent, like this.getParent().getIntent().getString("myString"); 


this.getParent().getIntent() <---- returns the calling intent, i.e the intent that called this activity...
```